# How to use iOS device as a Bluetooth controller for Android device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, games, remote-control, android

I was wondering if there's an app that allows an iOS device to be used as a Bluetooth controller for an Android device.

I've seen this setup made possible in a game, BombSquad. My Android device was running the [game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.froemling.bombsquad), while my iPod touch ran the [controller app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bombsquad-remote/id416471850) made by the same developer.

Is a way to have a similar, yet more universal setup? I imagined this being realized one of 2 ways:

1. An iOS app that emulates a normal Bluetooth controller
2. An iOS app that connects to an Android receiver app, similar to what Joypad Legacy and Ultimate Gamepad do for iOS/PC connections.

Do either of these exist? I've searched but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about bluetooth, so I suggest DLNA instead. I am able to remote control my LG tv via iPhone with that.